# Question about one sentence

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I got this sentence from the ros tutorial. It's located at helloworld\follow_the_route.py
line 43:

```
    # Navigation
    rospy.loginfo("Go to %s pose", name[:-4])
    success = navigator.goto(obj['position'], obj['quaternion'])
    if not success:
        rospy.loginfo("Failed to reach %s pose", name[:-4])
        continue
    rospy.loginfo("Reached %s pose", name[:-4])
```

I can't understand the sentence,

```
 rospy.loginfo("Go to %s pose", name[:-4])
```

What is `name[:-4]`?

I think name is enough to represent a string. what is `[:-4]` ? What is the syntax here?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/230481/question-about-one-sentence/) by [junjun](https://answers.ros.org/users/26432/junjun/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2016-03-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is rather a python than a ROS question.

With the syntax `name[:-4]` you get all but the last four elements of the sequence `name`.

You can easily test in a python console. E.g.

```
>>> name = 'ThisIsMyName'
>>> print name[:-4]
ThisIsMy
```

(Next time, please use the preformatted text button, the one with 1s and 0s, to format your question in a more readable format).

---

EDIT

A bit more background: This is also called *slicing*.

Whereas with most mutable sequences (like e.g. lists) you can change the sequence this way as well, strings are immutable and thus you cannot change them. For more info, check out [this article](http://pythoncentral.io/cutting-and-slicing-strings-in-python/) about slicing strings, as well as [the python doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types) about mutable sequence types.

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2016-03-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Akif](https://answers.ros.org/users/23527/akif/) on 2016-03-30**:
And for additional information, this is called as "slicing" in python. https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#strings

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2016-03-30**:
whoops, beat me by one minute :-D added some links as well...

**Comment by [Akif](https://answers.ros.org/users/23527/akif/) on 2016-03-30**:
You beat me on answer, so I added it as comment :) Though, it is a comprehensive answer now without my comment.

**Comment by [junjun](https://answers.ros.org/users/26432/junjun/) on 2016-03-30**:
Thank you for your answer. Comprehensive.